# Using "aren't they"?

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence "The apples are red, aren't they?" grammatically correct? If i remove the contraction it becomes, "The apples are red, are not they?" which does not sound right to me.

Comment: Related if not a dup: [Why does “Why doesn't it work?” become “Why does it not work?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82982/why-does-why-doesnt-it-work-become-why-does-it-not-work)

Comment: Acceptability in English is governed by usage rather than logical analysis. It's nice when they overlap.

Answer (score 1):

"Aren't they?" is perfectly acceptable, though you're right that "are not they?" sounds a little strange - you'd say "are they not?" if you wanted to avoid the contraction, though to my ears this sounds overly... dramatic?

Comment: It's more than "a little strange"; it's ungrammatical. Tag questions with negatives should be contracted whenever possible, and if they're not, then the negative goes **after** the subject, not before it -- i.e, _, are they not?_ is grammatical, but **, are not they?* isn't.