# not or n't - word order in negative questions

Tags: questions, negation

Here is the context:

> **Tom doesn't like eating apples, bananas and oranges.**

If I want to ask a question about what Tom doesn't like to eat, Which one of the followings is correct and sounds normal?

*What doesn't Tom like to eat?*

*What does Tom not like to eat?*

Thanks guys!

Comment: Both are grammatically correct but the first (_What doesn't Tom like to eat?_) sounds more normal to me.

Comment: They're both perfectly normal. The first is the contracted version of the second. Why does contraction work this way? See the question [Why does "Why doesn't it work?" become "Why does it not work?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82982/why-does-why-doesnt-it-work-become-why-does-it-not-work)

Answer (score -3):

The best answer can be found on your question:

If I want to ask a question about **what Tom doesn't like to eat**, Which one of the followings is correct and sounds normal?

:D

Comment: "*what Tom doesn't like to eat*" would not convey the same meaning as either "What doesn't Tom like to eat?" or "What does Tom not like to eat?".